# Azure durable function : 403 and 409 errors when writing internally to blob/queue/table. Do I need "Storage Account Contributor"?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-durable-functions

I have this **Azure Function** app in a corporate environment that's been around for quite some time and seems to be working as expected.
It's using a **User Managed identity**; among other things it lets it access the **Storage** resource.

Until now everything was working well because that Function application was triggered by Http triggers or Service Bus triggers and accessed some APIs to perform tasks.

Now I've been trying to add a **Durable Function** to it. Fail!

The http call to the function works, and the function starts doing its internal thing, but eventually fails. the end-to-end call shows **errors 403 and 409** on those kinds of internal calls:

- XXX.**blob**.core.windows.net PUT
- XXX.**table**.core.windows.net POST
- XXX.**queue**.core.windows.net POST

Which mad me wonder : Are my User Identity's permissions sufficient?

I can see in the IAM of the Storage resource that the identity does have these **roles** :

- **Storage Blob Data Contributor**
- **Storage Queue Data Contributor**
- **Storage Table Data Contributor**

My knowledge base for all this is this manual page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-configure-durable-functions-with-credentials
That page seems to confirm that those roles are enough.

Am I looking in the right direction?

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issue. Could you please share the complete error details (which includes the x-ms-request-id) from the 403 and 409 error message ? You can enable the storage diagnostic logs and gather this details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/manage-storage-analytics-logs?tabs=azure-portal

Comment: @NaveenBaliga see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The issue "fixed itself" the day after.

It **might** have been resolved by an **unrelated** upgrade of one of the following packages:

- Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions upgraded to 1.1.0
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions 4.0.1

Unfortunately I can't provide the previous versions (the ones that caused the issue).

I had however found a post on StackOverflow where someone fixed a similar issue by giving an "overkill" role to the managed identity. I mean, overkill in regards to what minimal roles the documentation prescribes.

This makes me think that maybe there was a bug at some point in the Functions library, which has been fixed since then.

Either that, or it was a weird delay in Azure applying changes or deploying resources (but 24 hours seems crazy).

I cannot provide more info, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the update. If the issue resurfaces, please feel free to share the complete error details (which includes the `x-ms-request-id` ) from the 403 and 409 error message. We would be happy to help.